# How to export selected products to xml in admin product grid

Tags: admin, grid, xml, grid-serlization, export

i need to export selected product to xml form admin product grid.

i have refer [**this**](http://forum.azmagento.com/magento-users-guide/export-products-to-csv-from-the-admin-product-grid-4663.html) to export selected product to csv.

Can anyone help for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the below code in

`[NameSpace]\[ModuleName]\Block\Adminhtml\IncreaseStock\Grid.php` Find the `_prepareColumns()` method and below line

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
   $this->addExportType('*/*/exportLowstockCsv', Mage::helper('stockincrease')->__('CSV'));
   $this->addExportType('*/*/exportLowstockExcel', Mage::helper('stockincrease')->__('Excel XML'));
}
```

Then it will automatically drop-down in Grid.